# Awaiting download with asyncio in Python

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

I'm working on a discord bot and I'm trying to implement a music player. I'm using discord and youtube-dl packages. This is the function that handles the play command (it's still a prototype):

```
@client.command(brief='Plays the song from the url.')
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice.is_playing():
        try:
            if 'song.mp3' in os.listdir(curr_dir):
                os.remove(os.path.join(curr_dir, 'song.mp3'))
            await download_to_mp3(url)
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(os.path.join(curr_dir, 'song.mp3')))
            voice.volume = 100
        except youtube_dl.DownloadError:
            await ctx.send('Invalid url.')
```

and also the download_to_mp3() function:

```
async def download_to_mp3(url):
    opts = {
        'outtmpl': os.path.join(curr_dir, 'song.webm'),
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
```

I meant it to work in such a way that while the download is being completed, I can still use other functions of the bot. As far as I understand the await statement says "Suspend the execution of the play() function, do something else while I'm waiting. When download_to_mp3 finishes, continue". However, it seems to read commands issued while downloading, but executes them only after the download is completed. How do I make it execute commands while downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand the await statement says "Suspend the execution of the play() function, do something else while I'm waiting. When download_to_mp3 finishes, continue"

That's exactly how it works, provided you follow the rules of async, the cardinal one being: **do not block during async**. Since `YoutubeDL.download` is apparently a blocking function (you don't await it), the execution of `download_to_mp3` stalls the whole event loop. The mere fact that there is no `await` statement in `download_to_mp3` tips you off that that function is async in name only.

The proper way to fix it is by swithing from `YoutubeDL` to an async downloader of the same kind, if one exists. If that's not an option, or if you need a quick fix, you can use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), which will execute a blocking function in a different thread, and return an awaitable object that suspends the awaiter until the blocking function is done. For example:

```
@client.command(brief='Plays the song from the url.')
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice.is_playing():
        try:
            if 'song.mp3' in os.listdir(curr_dir):
                os.remove(os.path.join(curr_dir, 'song.mp3'))
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            await loop.run_in_executor(None, download_to_mp3, url)
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
                os.path.join(curr_dir, 'song.mp3')))
            voice.volume = 100
        except youtube_dl.DownloadError:
            await ctx.send('Invalid url.')

# note: download_to_mp3 is now an ordinary function, not an async one
def download_to_mp3(url):
    ... the same definition as before ...
```

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you!